# Need help - setting up frontend environment

Tags: ruby, node.js, installation, yeoman, linux-mint

Hi I'm trying to setup a good front-end environment away from the vanilla html & css basic. I know the tools I need but cant work out how to get them all installed and setup in mint (which I'm new to) tools I'm trying to get setup are as follows, any help or guides that people can direct me to would be much appreciated, as many of the resources I come across are mac or windows related;

- ruby
- rvm
- gems
- node
- npm

  (yeoman)

  - sass
  - compass
  - grunt
  - bower

In short I guess what I really need is the correct and up to date commands for terminal, but i just cant seem to find a straight forward type this, install this, update this kind of guidance on their sites. its confusing the hell out of me, I can download them all, but don't then know how to run those files, my package manager keeps failing, and I'm unsure how to use those files that i have downloaded through the terminal.

E.G

```
sudo -s apt-get install node
sudo -s apt-get install node.js
sudo -s apt-get install npm
sudo -s apt-get install node.js version ?.?
sudo -s apt-get install node.js version ?.? /path/path/path
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a [PPA repository](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_Package_Archive) to install node.js, as it isn't in the main Mint repositories:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
```

After this, you can then update your local package lists and install node.js and npm:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install nodejs npm
```

This will then let you install the node libraries that you want:

```
$ npm install -g sass compass grunt bower
```

(Note the `-g` flag here which tells npm to install the packages globally)

---

To install RVM - which handles the installation of different Ruby (and `gem`) versions, you can find numerous guides on the internet (such as [this one](http://rubyflewtoo.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/installing-rvm-on-linux-mint-13.html)). The [official documentation](http://rvm.io/rvm/install) is also very useful. The process usually looks something like this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install curl
$ curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
$ source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
$ rvm requirements
$ rvm install <ruby version>
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I have encountered a couple of issues a long the way.. npm install -g sass
npm WARN excluding symbolic link index.js -> lib/sass.js
npm WARN excluding symbolic link lib/index.js -> sass.js  is this a problem?

Comment: I haven't experienced those messages myself, but I believe you can safely ignore them as it is simply saying some files couldn't be correctly symlinked into place. Perhaps try an `npm cache clear` and see if that gets rid of the warnings.

Comment: Note: I hadnt at the time, but I have now added my user to rvm group.

Comment: Ok thanks Jamie, I tried the cache clear but no luck. I shall ignore for now and continue with my rvm install... I have had the most trouble with that to be honest, but wasn't sure if this was due to my operating system? As two of the errors are it being related Debian & no binary ruby's being available. shall i post console errors to see if you might be able to help ?

Comment: I'm having Binary issue's Jamie, think you could help me out? https://gist.github.com/Matt5ander5/eddaaa489141e1c45100